# Class 'Stripe' not found using stripe-php and Slim Framework

Tags: stripe-payments, slim

I have included the PHP Stripe lib version 4.4.0 into my Slim Framework setup version 2.4.2. PHP version 5.4.16.

I autoload in the library using require ("../vendor/autoload.php");

However when I call:

```php
\Stripe::setApiKey($this->stripeKey);

$customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
                        'email' => $email,
                        'card'  => $token
                    ));
```

I get the error "Class 'Stripe' not found" I think its to do with the Slim Framework not integrating with Stripe.

I have downloaded https://github.com/collegeman/slim-common which is a Slim project that has Stripe integrated and that works ok, but I am looking to update the Stripe library to 4.4.0 (its latest version)

**Update**

When I remove "namespace Stripe;" from the stripe/stripe-php/lib/Stripe.php it proceeds to say "Class 'Stripe\Stripe' not found in /vendor/stripe/stripe-php/lib/ApiResource.php on line 16"

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [documentation](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php#getting-started) usage looks like the following:

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey($this->stripeKey);
```

Comment: Hi Mike, thank you for replying. I have updated but getting "Class 'Stripe\Stripe' not found in /vendor/stripe/stripe-php/lib/Stripe.php" back. Also I have updated my question when "namespace Stripe;"  is removed from the Stripe.php Class

Comment: You should include the vendor/autoload file

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a PHP version issue.

The recent versions of Stripe require PHP >= 5.6.0, see [the documentation here on GitHub](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php).

A few months ago, I attempted to install a slightly earlier version of Stripe (whatever was newest then) with PHP 5.4.16 and it generated the same exact error message.

I think you may need to upgrade PHP. Alternatively, you could try using an older version of Stripe that supports PHP 5.4. However this would not be a good solution; PHP 5.4 has reached end-of-life as of September 2015, a long time ago, and as a result may have a long list of concerns associated with it. Back when I was running PHP 5.4, over the past few years, I have run into a long list of problems with it, including it not working with newer software packages, and not supporting modern best-practices with respect to cryptography and other security measures. Even if you manage to get Stripe working here, you may run into other problems down the line, perhaps with Stripe, or perhaps with other software packages, security, etc.

At a bare minimum I recommend upgrading to 5.6, but as that version has already reached end-of-life too (December 2018) an actively-supported version such as 7.3 or greater would be better. I upgraded to 7.4 which is supported through November 2022 and will likely be supported for Stripe much longer than that, and it fixed the problem here, as well as a variety of other unrelated problems I had been having, although I did need to rewrite quite a lot of code in order to do the migration.